# Prolog Picking from a list and Summing specific Values

Tags: prolog

```
sumPicker([[]|_], Y, Z).
sumPicker([X|X1], Y, Z):-
   downList(Y, X, Sum),
   Total is Z,
   Z is Total + Sum,
   sumPicker(X1,Y, Z).
downList([Z|_], 1, Z).
downList([_|B],Count, Number):- Count > 1,
   SendCount is Count - 1,
   downList(B, SendCount, Number).
```

So this code is basically suppose to take in Two lists sumPicker([3,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6], X). The program then takes the first list and depending on the value of the number, so in this case 3, it will find the third number in the second list then it will find the 5th number of the second list and add them together.

ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated is what i am getting

Comment: You are trying to call `downlist` instead of `downList`

Comment: Thanks that solved the first problem

Comment: But i still cant see to fix the others

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your instructor would like you to work out the recursion yourself, rather than using built-in list operations. To that end, you could approach it something like this, using no built-ins at all.

A common prolog idiom is to have a simple "public" predicate that invokes a "helper" predicate that carries state (in this case, the current position in the list and the running sum). Often, that "helper" predicate will have the same functor (name) as the public predicate, with a higher arity (number of arguments).

So, first we have the public predicate, `sum_of_desired/3`:

```
sum_of_desired( Indices , Numbers , Sum ) :-      % to sum certain list elements,
  sum_of_desired( Indices , Numbers , 0 , Sum ) - % invoke the helper
  .                                               %
```

All it does is invoke the helper, `sum_of_desired/4`. This helper predicate carries an extra argument that is its *state*: an *accumulator* that contains the running sum. When it succeeds, that running sum is *unified* with the final total. This is because, in Prolog, **you can't change the value of a variable**: once you assign a value to a variable, **it ceases to be variable**. It become that with which it was unified (that's it's called *unification*). The only way to undo that assignment is via *backtracking*.

Typically, a recursive problem has a few *special cases* and a more general case. So, here, our helper predicate has 2 clauses:

- The first clause is the *special case*: the list of desired indices is empty, in which case the finally sum is the current value of the accumulator (0 initially).
- the second clause is the recursive general case: here we find the desired list item, add it to the running total and recurse down, moving on to the next item in the list of desired list items.

  ```
  sum_of_desired( []     , _ , S , S ) .  % the list of desired indices is empty: unify the   accumulator with the result.
  sum_of_desired( [I|Is] , L , T , S ) :- % otherwise...
    get_nth_item(I,L,N) ,                 % - get the nth item from the list
    T1 is T+N ,                           % - add it to the running total
    sum_of_desired(Is,T1,S)               % - and recurse down
    .                                     %
  ```

Finally, this predicate, `get_nth_item/3`, simple recursively walks the list, looking for the n<sup>th</sup> item in the list, where `n` is relative to 1 (e.g., the first item in the list is at index 1). When it finds it, it's returned as the 3rd argument of the predicate.

Again, here you will note that we have a single terminating *special case* and the more general recursive *special case*:

```
get_nth_item( 1 , [X|_]  , X ) .  % found it!
get_nth_item( N , [_|Xs] , R ) :- % otherwise...
  N > 1 ,                         % - if N > 1 , 
  N1 is N-1 ,                     % - decrement N
  nth_item( N1 , Xs , R )         % - recurse down.
  .                               % - easy!
```

Comment: Why does the first clause only have 3 arguments but the second can have four?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what sum_of_desired( []     , _ , S , S ) does i only started prolog last week

Comment: And reading the code you have T1 is T+N ,                           % - add it to the running total
  sum_of_desired(Is,T1,S) , so when you recall the program you seem to be sending back T1 which is the current sum of the numbers and S which is also the sum of the numbers? so when you recall the program you never send back the numbers?

Comment: WRT to your 1st comment, because they are **two different predicates:** they have the same *functor* (name) --`sum_of_desired` -- but their *arity* differs (3 versus 4). See my amended answer for a better explanation.